# Pass an environment variable to the URL launched by webpack-dev-server as query parameter

Tags: javascript, webpack, environment-variables

Currently I have launching the webpack-dev-server defined like this in package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
    ...
  }
```

When I start my app I see this in the console:

```
Project is running at http://localhost:4200/
```

...and my browser starts up at that URL.

What I'd like to be able to do is define an environment variable like this:

```
FOO=bar
```

And have that environment variable picked up in such a way that I get:

```
Project is running at http://localhost:4200/?foo=bar
```

Is this possible? If so, how might I do it?